# Change file names of images?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

I want to change the file names of images in my app, can i do this?

Comment: is this before or after you've built the app?

Comment: Are these images that are used within the app UI, or images that you have stored in your app that are user-content?  Can you provide more detail?

Comment: see this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454676/ios-objective-c-image-file-name-path-different-behavior-betwewen-simulator-and-de)

Comment: Images that come bundled with the app. I mean the actual image name, ie "picture.png".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is inside your [NSBundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html), then the answer is No.  If you copy an image from [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can name it whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in your NSBundle and you'd like to create a copy of the same image name, you can do that by loading the NSData and saving it with a different name. That just uses up extra space though.

Why are you trying to change the name of an image to begin with? If you needed to, you can create an NSMutableDictionary and a special function which takes a "filename" and returns the name of the actual image file in your NSBundle.

For example if you had a file named "MyImage.png" which part of your program thinks is actually called "ThatCoolPicture.png", you can load it like this:
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[self nameForPseudoname:@"ThatCoolPicture.png"]];

In this case nameForPseudoname takes a "nickname" and returns the real name.

Hope this helps!