# Thread 1: Program received signal:"Sigbart 1"

Tags: xcode, tableview, ios5

When I run the app in the iPhone Simulator, everything works just fine .. but with time I'll try to get my iPhone

> Thread 1: Application Received
>   signal:" Sigbart 1"

why?

Here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   

golfbaner *detailViewController = [[golfbaner alloc] initWithNibName:@"Golfbaner" bundle:nil];

detailViewController.golf = [banenavn objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];

}
```

XCode says it's HERE:

> [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

it goes wrong

I can admit that I'm quite a beginner.... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to be u are new bee.so here i assume u would be created the golfbaner with nib file .so it would be same as filename for nibname.

Golfbaner.NIB is not with your project.//check out this

maybe like golfbaner.NIB

so use

golfbaner *detailViewController = [[golfbaner alloc] initWithNibName:@"golfbaner" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is that `detailViewController` is nil. If you look at the console output it will tell you for certain.

The reason its nil on hardware is that the file system is case sensitive on hardware and hence

`golfbaner *detailViewController = [[golfbaner alloc] initWithNibName:@"Golfbaner" bundle:nil];`

"Golfbaner" != "golfbaner"

Check your nibname for case match. I suspect its "golfbaner.xib".

See [iOS Objective-C Image file name/path different behavior betwewen simulator and device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454676/ios-objective-c-image-file-name-path-different-behavior-betwewen-simulator-and-de)

As a style point class names should be capitalised otherwise it makes a class hard to separate from a variable when reading code.

Answer (score 0):

It may be spelling mistake after @"Golfbaner" 
just copy nibfile name and paste it.