# iOS file path differences between device and simulator

Tags: ios, filesystems, filepath

This is similar to this question: [iOS Objective-C Image file name/path different behavior betwewen simulator and device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454676/ios-objective-c-image-file-name-path-different-behavior-betwewen-simulator-and-d)

I have the following path in Xcode, where `Landscape` is a Folder, not a Group:

`Resources/Landscape/clouds_high.png`

Both these load the image in the Simulator:

```
// Version A. Should only work for Groups, where image is in root
[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"clouds_high.png"];
// Version B. Should work for my case (with a Landscape Folder)
[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Landscape/clouds_high.png"];
```

However, as expected, only the second works on the iOS device. I'm aware of differences in case causing things like this, but why does the first version with an invalid path still work in the Simulator?

For the record, if I make a duplicate of `clouds_high.png` just in the Resources directory, then the Simulator picks this version over the original in `Landscape` for Version A. Using Version B causes the simulator to choose the one in `Landscape` as expected. But as I mentioned before, the iOS device only works with the path specified relative to `Resources`. Why is this?

Comment: What is file structure in target .app folder, does `clouds_high.png` lie only in `Landscape` folder? (right click on app in Products pane, reveal in Finder and show package contents). And one more question: is this behavior the same after you delete app from Simulator and device and clean project?

Comment: Yep, the only instance of that file in the whole app is in the `Landscape` folder. And yes, I tried to clean and delete.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to get your paths. It will never fail, neither in the simulator nor on the device unless the file name you provide is invalid.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"clouds_high" ofType:@"png"];
```

For your case:

```
[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"clouds_high" ofType:@"png"]];
```

Comment: That returns a `(null)`... Not sure why.

Comment: which part returns null ? - pathForResource:ofType: or - spriteWithFile: ?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"clouds_high" ofType:@"png"]);` gave `(null)`

Comment: That means that you have not included the resource properly in your project. For me it works, no matter where in what directory or subdirectory in the bundle i copy the file. And as a recomandation, when you add files, choose "relative to project" from the options.